# How can I change blender´s 2.78 splash screen?

Tags: python, interface, image

I´m following this guide:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Windows/msvc/CMake
and so I got all the files for blender and I´m ready to change the splash screen on Blender 2.78a

So I read this:
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.4/Doc/How_to/Edit_the_SplashScreen

But on the 2.78 dependencies, there´s no file "datatoc.py", instead there´s a "ctodata.py" file. So when I run the python command:

```
python ctodata.py splash.png
```

I get error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ctodata.py", line 44, in 
    data = fpin.read().rsplit("{")[-1].split("}")[0]
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 968: char
acter maps to

Could someone help me out on how to change the splash screen on Blender 2.78a, please? Thanks.

Comment: ctodata.py cannot work. You need datatoc.py . The last version with datatoc.py included is 2.76b. Try grab it from there. The source code files of older versions can be found here: https://download.blender.org/source/ - I don't know the reason why it is not longer included. It should, you still need it. Could be by accident. Or intended for unknown reasons. Maybe somebody could ask the developers here.

Comment: Hm, i just found the commit where it was deleted. But no explanation why it was removed. Just that it is unused https://developer.blender.org/rBe83b3e577e59770dcd43a0c9dbf9ff3dcfda4365

Comment: @Tiles - Just a guess. It might got removed because Blender was "rebranded" and "repackaged" several times in the past by some people who then sold it to unaware customers.

Comment: @metaphor_set, everything is possible, but this makes imho no sense. And would be illegal against the gnu gpl 2 and 3, which forbids obfuscations. Blender is open source. And so people should be able to modify the source code. Including splash screen and icons. And it's also really easy to grab the datatoc.py file from previous versions. So i still wonder why it was removed. - I haven't compiled newer versions yet though. Is there a new way to create the icons and splash screen c files now? Is it now done internally without the datatoc.py file?

Comment: @Tiles - Oh, it does make sense. At least to people who don't care about what the GNU General Public license says. Have a seat, take a look: https://www.blender.org/press/re-branding-blender/

Comment: @metaphor_set, i know those cases. But fact is, even those evil forks are completely legal. They are just not nice and not fair. Obfuscation and removing vital parts from an open source project is illegal though. Blender would become the baddie here. - Campbell knows the gpl license too good to do such a bad thing. So i guess we overlook something here. Pierre Schiller, have you tried to change the png file directly? Does the change arrive in the build?

Comment: @Tiles - No, they are anything but completely legal. But BlenderSE isn't the place to discuss this matter.

Comment: Hello guys. So that was 2012, and Blender 2.6x could still manipulate splash images. How do I do it on Blender 2.78?

Comment: Pierre, the old method worked up to 2.76b. Have you meanwhile tried to modify just the png image? Does this modifications arrive in the build then? And if not, have you tried to grab the datatoc.py from an older build to do the conversion manually?

Comment: I grabbed datatoc.py from github (older version on blender), I did the conversion. But somehow it seems I can´t setup the environment for the build on MSVisual Studio 2015 community. Additionally the Make command the end of tutorial is throwing an error: Doesn´t recognize a compiler. Don´t know what else to do?

Answer (score 2):

I have meanwhile solved this one. The key is to rerun Cmake once you have modified the splash.png and splash_2x.png files. Cmake is where the conversion of the files happens. And that's why nothing happens when you just modify the files.

So modify the png files, clear cache in Cmake, configure in Cmake, generate in Cmake, then compile again.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! Now I will make changes on the ICONS also!! :D

Comment: Changing icons is a bit more complicated. I would suggest to open a new topic then when you get stuck :)

Comment: All icons are into 1 SVG file. Documents mention to change anything there. I won´t "add" new ones, I´ll replace the ones that are already there. Mono colors rule on design. :D

Comment: @PierreSchiller What happened to your project to change icons? you were successful, I am interested in knowing your results you can contact me in my profile links

Comment: Hi. I completed the complete course walk-through to do that and add other things for the UI, functions, etc. You can find it here: https://gum.co/cSCUn